# Accessing a list of open notebooks and a list of notebook cells in JupyterLab 4

Tags: jupyter-lab

How do I access:

- a list of open notebooks;
- a list of cells in a specific notebook

in JupyterLab 4?

I can generate a reference to the currently active cell in an active notebook:

```js
const plugin: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
  id: '@jupyterlab-examples/toolbar-button:plugin',
  description:
    'A JupyterLab extension adding a button to the Notebook toolbar.',
  requires: [INotebookTracker],
  autoStart: true,
  activate: (app: JupyterFrontEnd, notebookTracker: INotebookTracker) => {
    activeCell = notebookTracker.activeCell
    // Perform operations on active cell,
    // eg get/set metadata, set node class attributes
  })
};

export default plugin;
```

and then use the `activeCell` reference to get/set cell metadata (e.g. `activeCell.model.getMetadata("tags") as string[]`) and manipulate cell node class attributes in the rendered UI (e.g. `activeCell.node.classList.add('myclass')`).

I thought I might be able to capture "on-the-fly" references to notebooks as they are selected using:

```js
notebookTracker.currentChanged.connect((tracker, panel) => {
})
```

but I can't find lists of cells on `tracker` or `panel`?

In pseudo code, what I would like to do is:

- when a notebook is opened (or rendered, eg if Lab starts with opened notebooks in view):

  - iterate the cells;

*Cell references should support getting/setting cell metadata and manipulation of cell node class attributes.*

Comment: This answer on Juopyter Discourse forum seems to do the trick in terms of accessing notebooks: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-4-iterating-over-all-cells-in-a-notebook/20033/5?u=psychemedia

Comment: Blogged comments on a solution: https://blog.ouseful.info/2023/06/22/updating-the-empinken-extension-from-jupyterlab-3-x-to-4-x/